# Apply VLOOKUP in pandas and python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv called 'data.csv' which has:

```
EmployeeIDNumber
A
B
C
D
```

I have another csv called 'basic.csv' which has the same data but is jumbled:

```
MemberIdentifier
B
A
C
```

I want to use PANDAS to create a result sheet which has:

```
EmployeeIDNumber MemberIdentifier
A                A
B                B
C                C
D                Not Found
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this but the most powerful is the following,

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.csv_read('data.csv')

df = merge(df1, df2, left_on='EmployeeIDNumber', right_on='MemberIdentifier', how='left')
```

Here we are choosing the specific columns we wish to join our DataFrames on. If you wish to also include any reading in the `MemberIdentifier` columns that does not match anything in the `EmployeeIDNumber` columns then you can set `how='outer'`.